# Calculate percent return over certain time frame for each group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that contains daily price data for thousands of stocks. I'd like to calculate the percent change in the stock price for each stock over different time frames. Right now, I am putting all the stock symbols in a list and looping through my data frame with a standard "for loop" to calculate the different fields. This takes forever and there must be a faster way to achieve the same thing.

Here is what I am currently doing. I am looking for a faster and more efficient way of writing this:

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd

date1 = date(2020, 1, 1)
date2 = date(2020, 1, 2)
date3 = date(2020, 1, 3)
date4 = date(2020, 1, 4)

my_dict = {'ticker' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
           'close' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 5],
           'date' : [date1, date2, date3, date4, date1, date2, date3, date4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
print('')
print(df)
print('')

ticker_list = list(sorted(set(df['ticker'].tolist())))
final = pd.DataFrame()

for ticker in ticker_list:
    x = df[df['ticker'] == ticker]
    x.set_index('date', inplace=True)

    some_return = x.iloc[-1]['close'] / x.loc[date2:].iloc[0]['close'] - 1

    d = {"ticker": ticker, "some_return": some_return}

    temp = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[ticker])

    final = final.append(temp)

print(final)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Performance tip: Repeatedly appending or concatenating DataFrames destroys performance. Use an intermediate data structure, and create the DF once you have all the data.

Comment: @AMC, added example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever found a faster way since March, but here's an option assuming all the symbols have the same amount of data.

build dataframe with 1000 symbols; 7500 dates, and 7500 values

```
symbols = ['A'+ str(i) for i in range(1,1001)]
df_hold_list = []
for s in symbols[0:1001]:
    my_dict = {'ticker' : [s]*7500,
             'close' : [i for i in range(1,7501)],
             'date' : [d.date() for d in pd.date_range(start='1/1/2000', periods=7500)]}
    dft = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)  
    df_hold_list.append(dft)
df = pd.concat(df_hold_list, axis=0).reset_index()
```

create your analysis based on your period (selected by date).

```
# percent change from last date to selected date; this filters out all dates for all symbols first then uses group_by
ddate = date(2005, 1, 4)
# calculate rows for use in pct_change later; assumes all groups have same number of data points
rows = df.loc[df['date'] >= ddate].groupby('ticker').get_group((list(df.groupby('ticker').groups)[0])).shape[0]
# calculate percent change
df['pctchnge'] = df.loc[df['date'] >= ddate].groupby('ticker')['close'].pct_change(periods=rows-1)
#only last value is need; all others are nan
df_final = df.groupby('ticker').tail(1)[['ticker', 'pctchnge']]
```

On my PC it takes ~10 seconds to build the df and less than 5 seconds to create the final df.